# a product of two relations $R,T$ element of $A \times A$ is defined as? I don't understand?

Tags: relations

$[RT = { (a, c) | \exists b \in A : (a, b) \in R \wedge (b, c) \in T }.]$

so i dont understand why a product of two relations is defined like that?
product stands for * , so shouldnt it be a Cartesian product of two tuples?
or do i understand the definition of a product of a cartesian product wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a *product* per se, I would instead call it a *composition*.  [This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_relations) may shed more light on the topic.  You should be well familiar with composition of functions at this point from example, this acts just the same.

Comment: @JMoravitz that makes absolutely sense, thank you!